# storageState not being set in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

After following the instructions on the official Playwright page to set the storageState, I find that nothing actually gets saved:

Steps are as follows:

(1) I create the global-setup.ts file:

```
async function globalSetup() {
    const requestContext = await request.newContext();
    let foo = await requestContext
        .post('https://some/page/signin', {
        form: {
            'username': 'xxx',
            'password': 'yyy',
            'remember': 'on'
        }
    });
    // Save signed-in state to 'storageState.json'.
    await requestContext.storageState({ path: 'storageState.json' });
    await requestContext.dispose();
}

export default globalSetup;
```

(2) Then, the storageState is called from the playwright.config.ts file:

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test'

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
    timeout: 60000,
    retries: 0,
    use: {
        // Tell all tests to load signed-in state from 'storageState.json'.
        storageState: 'storageState.json',
        headless: false,
        viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
        actionTimeout: 15000,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        video: 'retain-on-failure',
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    },
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'Chromium',
            use: { browserName: 'chromium' },
        }
    ],
}
export default config
```

However, when checking the storageState.json file that is created, I get the following:

```
{
  "cookies": [],
  "origins": []
}
```

I am not sure why the cookies and origins are empty as the request had returned a 200 response which means the request itself was fine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `'storageState.json'`, can you try this

```
await requestContext.storageState({ path: storageState });
```